# Moving HTML element to bottom by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML code as below:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
  <div id="foo"></div>
  <div id="bar"></div>
  <div id="four"></div>
  <div id="five"></div>
  <div id="six"></div>
  <div id="seven"></div>
</div>
```

I want to move `<div id="foo"></div>` and `<div id="bar"></div>` to the bottom under `<div id="seven"></div>`. Should I use `insertAfter()` or `after()` or any jQuery function is better to achieve this requirement?

Thanks

Comment: I would think using the DOM and javascript would do nicely. After all, jQuery uses it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

appendTo will move the elements to the end of the element's DOM

```
$('#foo, #bar').appendTo('#wrap');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `.after()`:

```
$('#seven').after($('#foo, #bar'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following piece of code:

```
$('#wrap').append('<div id="foo"></div>')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I could after a little read thru... I needed something a little more generic to be used across the site:

BROWSER TESTED: Chrome, Firefox, IE7, IE8, IE9

**OBJECTIVE**... move "Other" to bottom... The server side code had no way of changing the markup.

```
<select name="anyName" id="anyID" >
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  <option value="Entry 1" >Entry 1</option>
  <option value="Entry 2" >Entry 2</option>
  <option value="Entry 3" >Entry 3</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("select option").each(function() {
        if($(this).text() === "Other" && $(this).parent("select").children("option:last-child").text() !== "Other") { 
            $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent("select").children("option:last-child"));
        }
    });
 }); 
</script>
```